# SQLITE3 query in Python using current_user.email

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-login

I need to fetch rows of a table called **records** in SQLite based on a conditional query that selects only records that match value of email column = current_user.email. Current_user is the proxy for current logged in user, so I want this table to filter records only showing the records applicable to this user.

```
rows = c.execute("select * from records where email = current_user.email").fetchall()
```

There is no problem is resolving value of current_user.email. I can print it and it shows me the email. The problem is in the query the way and the way I am implementing it, does not filter the records. However when I replace current_user.email with the actual email id in quotes, for example "xyz@xyz.com", it filters perfectly.
So my question is how can I filter Sqlite column based on a value that is another variable (here: email = **current_user.email**), and not email = **"xyz@xyz.com**?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `?` placeholder in the sql statement, then pass the specific value you're looking for as an extra argument.

```
rows = c.execute("select * from records where email = ?", [current_user.email]).fetchall()
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it has worked using this. @john Gordon

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the content of the variable to your string. Right now, your SQL driver just sees "select * from records where email = user.email"

The code below should help.

```
rows = c.execute("select * from records where email = %(username)", {"username": current_user.email}).fetchall()
```

Bad Code that is vulnerable to SQL injection.

```
rows = c.execute("select * from records where email = {}".format(current_user.email)).fetchall()
```

Thanks to John Gordon for pointing it out.

Comment: This is vulnerable to sql injection attack.  Don't do this.